# Python: Nest more than two types of quotes

Tags: python, nested, quotes

Is it possible to nest more than two types of quotation signs? I mean I know `'` and `"` but what if i need more?
Is this allowed:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo "var1+'hello!'+var2"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use triple-quotes to avoid any kind of problem with nested *single* quotes:

```
subprocess.Popen('''echo "var1+'hello!'+var2"''', shell=True)
```

In case you want to use the same triple-quotes as both a delimiter *and* inside the string then you have to escape the quotes in the string:

```
'''some\'\'\'triple quotes\'\'\'''' -> "some'''triple quotes'''"
```

Alternatively you can rely on the fact that the interpreter will concatenate consecutive string literals, and use different quotes for different parts of the string:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo "var1+' "'hello!'" '+var2"', shell=True)
```

Note that in this way you can even mix raw strings with non-raw strings:

```
In [17]: print('non\traw' r'\traw' 'non\traw')
non     raw\trawnon     raw
```

Comment: Before Python 3.12, reusing the same quotes as the enclosing f-string raises a SyntaxError.  

Starting with Python 3.12, there is no limit on how many times you repeat the same type of quotes inside the nested quotes. In Python 3.12, you can now do things like this:  
<br>

`songs = ['Take me back to Eden', 'Alkaline', 'Ascensionism']  
f"This is the playlist: {", ".join(songs)}"  
'This is the playlist: Take me back to Eden, Alkaline, Ascensionism'`  


See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#whatsnew312-pep701 for more.

Comment: In between two such string literals you can even have a newline. I use this a lot to break up long lines of code printing comparatively short texts. Makes it more readable. I dislike having to add the `end=''` parameter, with additional function call making it less obvious what's printed on the same line, and what's printed on the next

Answer (score 6):

Triple quotes work. You can use either `'''` or `"""`

```
subprocess.Popen('''echo "var1+'hello!'+var2"''', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use triple quotes:

```
subprocess.Popen('''echo "var1+'hello!'+var2"''', shell=True)


subprocess.Popen("""echo "var1+'hello!'+var2\"""", shell=True)
```